# Bootstrap Colorpicker, How to set color value box inside dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, color-picker

I'm using [Bootstrap Colorpicker 2.3](https://mjolnic.com/bootstrap-colorpicker), but my requirement is, I want to add the text field value box inside the color picker, [like this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msvZ7.png), is it possible ? could you somebody help me please, thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try something ?

Comment: I tried to findout on their website for was there any kind options for me, but there seem no option by them officially, can we try any solutions our self please ? or could anyone tell me if there any other jQuery plugins similarly to my example (screenshot) ? much help helpful if there...

I only wanted the color picker and a value set box inside the picker...

Comment: they provided an option called `template` . check that in source code and change it as per your requirement

Comment: @JSantosh Thank you for your kind effort to help me, but unfortunately it's doesn't work, I've tried with the template as this screenshot

http://i.imgur.com/05A8pCP.png

the box comes inside the color picker but not working either pick or stores
http://i.imgur.com/KeY9Hzm.png

Comment: can you provide a fiddle ? I'll try to debug

Comment: Yes sure, now I've created a fiddle to show you, could you check here please https://jsfiddle.net/xd6cadq7/

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Updated your fiddle with some additional code.

Plugin has `changeColor` event . Use this to update input element value.

```
$('.demo2').on('changeColor.colorpicker', function(a, b, c) {
    $('.store').val($(this).colorpicker('getValue'))
});
```

```js
$('.demo1').colorpicker();

$('.demo2').colorpicker({
  template: '<div class="colorpicker dropdown-menu">' +
    '<div class="colorpicker-saturation"><i><b></b></i></div>' +
    '<div class="colorpicker-hue"><i></i></div>' +
    '<div class="colorpicker-alpha"><i></i></div>' +
    '<div class="colorpicker-color"><div /></div>' +
    '<div class="colorpicker-selectors"></div>' +
    '<div class="colorpicker-selectors"></div>' +
    '<input type="text" value="" class="store" />' +
    '</div>',
  input: '.store'
});


$('.demo2').on('changeColor.colorpicker', function(a, b, c) {
  $('.store').val($(this).colorpicker('getValue'))
});
```

```css
.demo1,
  .demo2 {
    width: 200px;
    margin: 30px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="/css/normalize.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/result-light.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-colorpicker/2.3.0/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-colorpicker/2.3.0/css/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">





<div class="input-group demo1">
  <input type="text" value="" class="form-control" />
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i></i></span>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
  <div class="field-title">With template</div>
  <div class="input-group input-picker demo2">
    <input type="text" value="" class="form-control" />
    <div class="dss"></div>
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i></i></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ftjq4e44/)

Comment: Thank you J Santosh for your effort to help me, actually I wanted the input text box not only change by dragging the picker, also looking for able to put value into the input box to get the user value its self, anyway I really appreciate your help, thank you for your great time :).

Comment: i tried that too, but was unable to enter . you give it a try once.